# Best Way to implement an Attendance Tracker using sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, infopath

Please let me know what is the best Way to implement an Attendance Tracker using SharePoint, using SharePoint Designer/InfoPath tools.

Comment: do you mean automatically, such as when a user 'logs in' into the system he is tracked as 'present'? or manual where the user himself or another person confirms the attendance?

Comment: not automatically. i meant using custom lists such as employee details, tracker etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should first create a new content type with name Attendance. The content type should have minimum following site columns

1. Employee Number (This will be the unique id which can identify the employee
2. Date (This will be the date value which indicate the employee has worked on that date or not)

You can add more relevant fields like department or total hours worked for the date etc.

Next create a custom list and using advanced property set the content type you created above.

You can done with the setup. Now users or manager can start filling in the list.

References

[Creating new content type](http://www.petri.com/create-new-content-type-sharepoint-2013.htm)

[Creating custom list](http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/create-list-in-sharepoint-2013.html)

[Adding content type to the list](https://support.office.com/en-CA/Article/Add-a-content-type-to-a-list-or-library-917366ae-f7a2-47ad-87a5-9689a1884e60)

Answer (score 0):

by custom list you mean something that you create from scratch? because i have seen 'contacts' and "issue tracking" but never employee details or other tracker. The easiest thing would be a calendar where everybody voluntarily fills in if they are in office or not. If other people are writing the attendance just add  a people field where the inputters can select the person.